# formatting string inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a string which looks like this

```
 payload = "{{\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{\n  \n  \t\"video\" :\"{}\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"{}\"\n  }\n}}".format(video_url, image)
print(payload)
```

as you see, i am trying to format this string, due to which i have added additional a set of open and closed brackets.But when i run this, i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video_match_output.py", line 12, in <module>
    payload = "{{\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{\n  \n  \t\"video\" :\"{}\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"{}\"\n  }\n}}".format(video_url, image)
KeyError: '\n  \n  \t"video" '
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful ,Thanks in advance.

This is the desired output-

```
    payload = "{\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{\n  \n  \t\"video\" :\"https://tech/api/files/89083/download/GaQuEpoDoWFh8u5HIWBmNIMgsIE58mCUHXVAOGBnU0lmC9HYHe.blob\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"tech/api/files/5860111/download/VsZU1fWulpbsZ1c1zUmF28EhRT3OH1XpHphilaLQRF2E67Tb76.png\"\n  }\n}"
```

Comment: let me update this

Comment: Are you trying to output JSON? If so you should use the actual `json` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP:  *due to which i have added additional a set of open and closed brackets.But when i run this, i get*

Not before but at every place where it shouldn't be:

```
video_url = "http://www.video-url.com"
image = "image_sample.jpg"
payload = "\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{{\n  
\n  \t\"video\" :\"{}\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"{}\"\n  }}\n".format(video_url, image)
print(payload)

# or if you're trying to dump JSON:
print("\nPrinting through JSON..\n")

import json
mydict = {"payload": payload}
print(json.dumps(mydict))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  "task" : "videoFaceMatch",  
  "essentials":{      
    "video" :"http://www.video-url.com",
    "matchImage" :"image_sample.jpg"
  }

Printing through JSON..

{
 "payload": "\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{\n 
 \n  \t\"video\" :\"http://www.video-url.com\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"image_sample.jpg\"
 \n  }\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
payload = "{{\n  \n  \"task\" : \"videoFaceMatch\",  \n  \"essentials\":{{\n  \n  \t\"video\" :\"{}\",\n  \t\"matchImage\" :\"{}\"\n  }}\n}}".format("video_url", "image")
print(payload)
```

**Output:**

```
{

  "task" : "videoFaceMatch",  
  "essentials":{

    "video" :"video_url",
    "matchImage" :"image"
  }
}
```